# JSON data as message for PubSub

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, publish-subscribe, google-cloud-pubsub

I have written the following code according to the Google "Publishing messages to topics" Guide:

```
import (
        "context"
        "fmt"
        "io"
        "cloud.google.com/go/pubsub"
)

func publishMessage(w io.Writer, projectID, topicID) error {
        msg := `{
                  "source":"test_source",
                  "data": {
                          "jobId": "123",
                          "recordCount": 10000
                          }
                }`
        ctx := context.Background()
        client, err := pubsub.NewClient(ctx, projectID)
        if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("pubsub.NewClient: %v", err)
        }

        t := client.Topic(topicID)

        result := t.Publish(ctx, &pubsub.Message{Data: []byte(msg)})
        id, err := result.Get(ctx)
        if err != nil {
                return fmt.Errorf("Get: %v", err)
        }
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Published a message; msg ID: %v\n", id)
        return nil
}
```

But each time I receive the error in logs of my Cloud Function:

> "com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: expected BEGIN_OBJECT, but was STRING"

I'd be grateful if you have any ideas on how to fix that.

- The subscription delivery type: **push**
- Cloud Function Trigger: **Topic**

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a Go question, but rather a NodeJS question. Despite the question is completely missing the Cloud Function's code, I still can tell what is wrong with it: Since you are pushing string instead of JSON, you have to use `JSON.parse(string);` before being able to use GSON on it.

---

If you want a Go answer, you'd probably need to push JSON, to begin with.

In Go one can encode JSON with [`json.Marshal()`](https://blog.golang.org/json) (`data object` could be defined as `struct`):

```
type Message struct {
    source string
    data object
}
msg := Message{ ... }
payload, err := json.Marshal(msg)
```

---

It doesn't really matter on which end you'd fix the problem created by pushing a JSON string instead of a JSON. The second one approach might probably be a tad better than the first one (in terms of already providing the expected format, instead of messing around later on). This is based upon, that a JSON and a JSON string are not the same thing (not even with identical content).